# Noise problem with Arduino + relay + motor unit

Tags: arduino

I use an Arduino + relay + motor unit, got electronic interference and the unit lost control. I search out that I need separate power supply for Arduino and load.
My question is if they still use common ground, can the common ground separate the noise?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they still need to share common ground.  Exceptions are when [optical couplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) are used.  But this is usually an extreme case where ground loops need to be avoided or isolation from a dangerous power level is required.

Note, mitigating noise at the source is usually the best option.  In this case are you using a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) across your relay's coil to suppress or eliminate flyback current from the coil's inductor characteristics?  Or placing capacitors across your motor as discussed in [this stackexchange.com question / answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153628/reduction-of-dc-motor-noise) to suppress noise from the motor?