# Reduce noise coming from DC brushless fan

Tags: power, noise, fan

First of all, I'm an amateur when it comes to electronics so thanks for your patience!

I have added a fan on a sound processor which tends to overheat but then I discovered I can hear the fan on the outputs.
The fan is being powered off the 15V line via a DC-DC converter to reduce the voltage to 10.5V approx.

I have two issues here:

1. Radiated noise: I placed the fan close to the analogue circuitry and it's picking up the EMI generated by the fan. So I'll have to relocate it.
2. I have noise coming back through the power supply. I can scope it on the line itself and at the audio outputs.

I've tried replacing the DC-DC converter (notoriously noisy) with a resistor and also a linear regulator but the noise is still there.

Is there anything I can add to mitigate this issue?

[image: This is a crude schematic of the circuit]
[image: This is the noise on the output]
[image: This is what I see on the line with a linear regulator]

First picture is is a crude schematic

Second picture is the noise at the sound output. The peak disappears if I stop the fan manually.

Third picture is the noise at the fan DC line.

Comment: What's the second picture probing? Regardless if the DCDC converter doesn't cause the noise but the fan alone does, get a different fan or move it away from the sensitive electronics. Often airflow is ducted anyway, you could do this.

Comment: Does [Reduction of DC motor noise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153628/reduction-of-dc-motor-noise) help?

Comment: Second picture is the sound output of the processor when nothing is playing. I tried different fans, they all seem to show the same issue. This is a San-Ace one, should be decent quality? And yes, I have moved the fan away already, my problem here is noise going back to the main PCB via DC supply. If I stop the fan manually, all that noise disappears, including at the main otuputs. @andrew I'll take a look thanks!

Comment: put a capacitor across the fan supply. as an added bonus you could then put a resistor in series before the fan; not enough to slow the fan much, but enough slack to give the capacitor more "room" on that side of the resistor to even out the voltage better.

Comment: Yes @dandavis, that has worked! I added a 10Ohm resistor and a 1000uF capacitor and the noise disappeared altogether. I'll update the thread soon!